# add key to nested array with condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a simple datastructure in mongodb:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID,
 name: 'Name',
 birthday: '25.05.2001'
 items: [
          {
             _id: ObjectID,
             name: 'ItemName',
             info: 'ItemInfo',
           },
           {
             _id: ObjectID,
             name: 'ItemName',
             info: 'ItemInfo',
           }
        ]
}
```

Now i want a query, that takes a ObjectID (_id) of an item as criteria and gives me back the object with all items in the array AND projects a new field "selected" with value true or false into a field in the result of each array item:

I tried that with this query:

```
 { $unwind: '$items' },
 {
    $project: {
       selected: {
          $cond: { if: { 'items._id': itemObjectID }, then: true, else: false },
      },
    },
  },
```

but MongoDB gives me back an error:

```
MongoError: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.
```

Have no clue why its not working, any help or ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) aggregation operator which checks the condition for the equality.

You can try below aggregation here if you want to check for `ObjectId` then you need to put `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id)`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$items" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "items.selected": {
      "$eq": [
        1111,
        "$items._id"
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "items": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$items._id",
        "selected": "$items.selected"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Will give following output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": 1111,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "_id": 2222,
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "name": "Name"
  }
]
```

You can check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9dmMiuVNpD8)

Comment: Thanks! I found my solution with your help. I posted it as an answer to my own question because of the large code part...thx

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish: Thank you very much for your help! Your answer helped me to build the right query for me:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "items.name": 0,
      "birthday": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "items.selected": {
        "$eq": [
          1111,
          "$items._id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      items: {
        $push: "$items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "items._id": {
        $eq: 1111
      }
    }
  },
])
```

and leads to a result that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": 1111,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "_id": 2222,
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "name": "Name"
  }
]
```

Comment: HI @Vizari, Actually what you are doing wrong here is `$match` and `$project`... The `$match` should be used  as soon as possible and the `$project` should be used at the end of the aggregation... And also you don't need to use `$project` here... You can see my updated answer...

Comment: Hi @Ashish, thanks for your reply. If i dont use the `$project` i have to add each field of the root document that i want to have in my result with "name": `{ "$first": "$name" }` and `$push: "$items"`for my nested object?. And if i put the '$match' at the beginning of my aggregation i have only the nested object that matches that criteria in my result, but i need all of them because they have to be marked as "selected: false"